# Windows 10 - WUApiLib exception

Tags: c#, windows-10, windows-update

i've written a tool to automate some windows update tasks for Windows 7 & Windows 8.1.

Testing the tool under Windows 10 now throws a System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException with the error code HRESULT: 0x80080005 (CO_E_SERVER_EXEC_FAILURE) while creating the first object from IAutomaticUpdates like this:

```
private IAutomaticUpdates _automaticUpdates = new AutomaticUpdates();
```

I'm sure the reason are the changes in the whole windows update process - but i can't find an adequate new API to manipulate Windows Update via C#.

Anyone got a hint for me?

Greetz

Comment: Compiling the application with Platform Target "AnyCPU" solves the problem. Unfortunately my application relies on being "x86".